# How to change background color item with click in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application I have `RecyclerView` and use **DiffUtils** for **Adapter** of `recyclerview`. 
I want **change background** color item of `recyclerview` when **click** on this. 
And when click on another item, then new item set background and previous item back to default color. 
I write below codes and work finally. 
But in this code I used **notifyDataSetChange** and I don't want use this method! 
What is the best solution for my work? 
**My codes:**

```
class HeartRateAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<HeartRateAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemSelectDialogBinding
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private var moviesList = emptyList<Data>()
    private var selectedItem = -1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemSelectDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        context = parent.context
        return ViewHolder()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //getItem from PagingDataAdapter
        holder.bind(moviesList[position])
        //Not duplicate items
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = moviesList.size

    inner class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bind(item: Data) {
            binding.apply {
                selectedTxt.text = item.description
                //Click
                binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                    selectedItem = adapterPosition
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    onItemClickListener?.let {
                        it(item)
                    }
                }
                //Change color
                if (selectedItem == adapterPosition) {
                    binding.selectedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle_selected)
                } else {
                    binding.selectedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle_un_selected)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Data) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Data) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    fun setData(data: List<Data>) {
        val moviesDiffUtil = NotesDiffUtils(moviesList, data)
        val diffUtils = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(moviesDiffUtil)
        moviesList = data
        diffUtils.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    class NotesDiffUtils(private val oldItem: List<Data>, private val newItem: List<Data>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return oldItem.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return newItem.size
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldItem[oldItemPosition] === newItem[newItemPosition]
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldItem[oldItemPosition] === newItem[newItemPosition]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain why you don't wanna use it ?
I used notifyDataSetChange

Comment: @MãĴď Because android studio suggested not use it

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use notifydatasetchanged, You can update the specific position of the item with notifyItemChanged()

```
 private fun updateItemBackground(position: Int) {
    if (selectedItem != -1) {
        // Reset the background color of the 
        previously selected item
        notifyItemChanged(selectedItem)
    }
    // Update the background color of the clicked item
    selectedItem = position
    notifyItemChanged(selectedItem)
}
```

add it to your click

```
 fun bind(item: Data) {
        binding.apply {
            selectedTxt.text = item.description
            // Click
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                // Update background color of the 
       clicked item
                updateItemBackground(adapterPosition)
                onItemClickListener?.let {
                    it(item)
                }
            }
            // Change color
            updateItemBackground(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
```

You can try in your code this way

```
inner class ViewHolder : 
     RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind(item: Data) {
    binding.apply {
        selectedTxt.text = item.description
        // Change color
        if (item.isSelected) {
            binding.selectedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle_selected)
        } else {
            binding.selectedImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle_un_selected)
        }
        // Click
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            // Update background color of the clicked item
            updateItemBackground(adapterPosition)
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

 private fun updateItemBackground(position: Int) {
    if (selectedItem != -1) {
        // Reset the background color of the previously selected item
        moviesList[selectedItem].isSelected = false
        notifyItemChanged(selectedItem)
    }
    // Update the background color of the clicked item
    selectedItem = position
    moviesList[selectedItem].isSelected = true
    notifyItemChanged(selectedItem)
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but where can I change background color? I can't find it in your code

Comment: Ok, please check code the answer again i wrote where to apply under.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I tried your code but when click on each item, set selected color! when click on new item not back previous item to default color!

Comment: Sorry friend, I didnt get that, you might need to do the correct logic for your usecase yourself, you know i just gave an alternatie for notifyDatasetChanged() that you can leverage on